# Transparent JPanel not working correctly

Tags: java, swing

I want my `JPanel` to be semi transparent. This panel is animated and has the motion of a dropdown list. I have used the `Color(r,g,b,a)` constructor to achieve the transparency, however the transparency only takes effect as the panel returns to its original position. For example, as it is moving downwards it is not transparent at all, however when moves up, it spontaneously becomes transparent.
How do I fix this problem?

```
detailPanel.setBackground(new Color(50,50,50,220));
detailPanel.setLayout(null);
detailPanel.setBounds(0,posY,1200,750);
```

Comment: <insert sigh> Like all the other questions before you on this subject (sorry, but it's really tiring to keep seeing it), you can't use a alpha based color when setting the background color of a Swing component, they can only be fully opaque or fully transparent, otherwise the repaint manager won't know that it should be painting the components beneath yours and you'll end up with all sorts of weird artifacts.  Instead, you need to make the component fully transparent (`setOpaque(false)`) and override it's `paintComponent` and fill it with your transparent color (fake it in other words)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526190/jframe-with-background-image-and-a-jpanel/31527567#31527567)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the cause of the problem (you can't use a transparent Color on an opaque background) and a couple of solutions to fix the problem:

1. make the component non-opaque and paint the background yourself
2. use the `AlphaContainer` class so it can do the painting of the background for you